# java: how do I stop people from clearing my arraylist<string> When I use a getter method?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have declared my arraylist in class A:

```
private ArrayList<String> user = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have created my getter method in the same class (Class A):

```
public ArrayList<String> getUser()
{
return user;
}
```

Then in my second class (Class B) I am able to do the following:

```
A UD = new A();
UD.getUser().clear();
UD.getErrmsg().clear();
```

how do I prevent my second class from clearing the arraylist in my first class (class A)?

Comment: `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)`.

Comment: What is said twice already, or use Guava and its `ImmutableList`; however that does not prevent the setter problem from happening too

Comment: What you need is to make what is called a defensive copy. Check this question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743513/defensive-copy-from-effective-java. The previous suggestions accurately mention how this is done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method for this in the `Collections` class you can use: `return Collections.unmodifiableList(user);` There are various other methods you might need, including ones for maps and so forth. Just take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-).

Answer (score 2):

Solution for both the getter *and* the setter:

```
public void setMyList(final List<String> list)
{
    myList = new ArrayList<>(list);
}

public List<String> getMyList()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

Using Guava:

```
public void setMyList(final List<String> list)
{
    myList = ImmutableList.copyOf(list);
}

public List<String> getMyList()
{
    return list;
}
```

If you can afford it, use Guava.