# Sonar Issue - Array is directly stored

Tags: java, arrays, sonarqube

I have a method wherein i'm directly assigning the method argument to a class variable.

```
public void sample(String[] targets)
{
    this.objects = Targets;
}
```

One solution i found out is creatig a new copy of the array using Arrays.copy(targets). But i'm worried if this would effect the performance of the system.

I have two questions :

Firstly, how big the Impact is if i use Arrays.copy().

If the Impact is big(if the array length is high), then is there any other solution to fix this sonar issue without impacting the Performance.

Comment: You'd have to measure the performance impact on your application and decide if it is acceptable to you. If you can't accept the hit of copying an array, you likely have other problems, but your only other solution is to ensure that nothing else is able to modify the array elements, removing the need to copy them.

Comment: You can consider using System.arrayCopy(..) for better performance.

Comment: Unless your application is running on a huge scale, you won't notice a difference in performance, especially if the array isn't very large.  By the way, you don't need Arrays.copy at all;  all arrays have an implicit public `clone()` method that throws no exceptions.  `this.objects = targets.clone();` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The Sonar hint advises you to make a [defensive copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743513/defensive-copy-from-effective-java) of the given array. Generally speaking, you should follow that advise, because otherwise, your code could produce bugs, which are caused by unwanted [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) and therefor hard to localize.

Usually, the performance impact by defensive copying is neglectible, due to it's unnoticeable overhead. More important for the decision pro/against defensive copy is its influence on other aspects of code quality, such as readibility, usability and stability.

As long as `sample()` is called infrequently, you don't need to hesitate making array copies.

Comment: Even if performance impact of defensive copy is neglegible, do you feel use of final method argument a better option than copying?

Comment: This is a common misconception. `final` for method arguments does not provide any security as the client still can modify the referenced object.