# How to implement a defensive copy correctly if Collection contains mutable items?

Tags: java, collections, immutability

Could you please clarify me what is the best way to ensure class immutability if the class contains a Collection and the items in the Collection represent mutable data?

From my point of view it should be done like this:

```
public class DateContainer {

    private final List<Date> dates;

    public DateContainer(List<Date> dates) {
        this.dates = new ArrayList<>();;
        for (Date date : dates) {
            this.dates.add(new Date(date.getTime()));
        }
    }

    public void addItems(Date date) {
        Date temp = new Date(date.getTime());
        dates.add(temp);
    }

    public List<Date> getItems() {
        List<Date> temp = new ArrayList<>();;
        for (Date date : dates) {
            temp.add(new Date(date.getTime()));
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(temp);
    }

}
```

But the solution above doesn't seem to be a concise one.
Also, what should I do if instead of Date, the type of items doesn't provide public copy constructor? How should I defensive copy them in this situation?

Comment: Note that in this particular case, you should avoid `java.util.Date` and migrate to `java.time` classes - see e.g. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html.

Comment: perhaps duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743513/defensive-copy-from-effective-java

Comment: This isn't a concise solution because you keep repeating yourself. You could factor out the list copying from the ctor and getter method: and you could factor the "copy the date and add to the list" out of that.

Comment: If there is no copy ctor, you would need a `Function<T, T>` which does the copying for you.

Comment: Date is a badly designed value class, which should have been immutable, and that everybody uses (or rather used, since it's now obsolete) as if it was immutable. For actual objects which are mutable, most of the time, they're mutable for a reason, and making a copy will probably break code, because the code will expect mutations to have an effect on the elements stored in the list. If that's not the case, the container should probably not contain mutable data in the first place, but immutable copies or adapters.

Comment: By the way, your example correctly implements a defensive copy in the sense that the getter returns a copy of dates, and also that dates is final and there is no setter.

The fact that Date is mutable isn't relevant if you only provide a copy and there is no way to "set" dates, or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Guillem, I am just wondering how to implement defensive copy if mutable items don't have copy constructors or overridden clone methods

Comment: You can't, in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pavel!

Your example is a good in a question of defensive copy. Actually, your class is immutable because the internals cannot be modified.

And what about mutable elements inside a collection, generally you shouldn’t care about it as almost always mutable classes are created intentionally due to some reasons.